# Using a Variant of BinarySearch to Find the Maximum in a Bitonic Array

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

Here is my code, where `a` is the array to find the maximum of (each element is distinct). From my perspective, if `a[mid]` is less than `a[mid-1]` then the position of the maximum should be in the range of `[lo, mid-1]`. However, when I implement my idea, the program is endless. The solution is to use `[lo, mid]` as the next iteration.

My question is: Why shouldn't I use `mid-1` instead of `mid` in Line 9?

**First edit: Some people ask why didn't I just sort and choose the first element?** Since the problem is to find a key in a bitonic array (where elements ascend first then descend). My solution is to find the maximum of the array, separate it into two parts and respectively use BinarySearch to find the key. If I sort the array I will destroy the original order.

**Second edit: add more code in detail and the expected output.**

```
public static int getMaxIndex(int[] a) {
    int hi = a.length - 1;
    int lo = 0;
    while (lo < hi && a[lo] <= a[lo+1]) {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if (a[mid] > a[mid-1]) {
            lo = mid;
        } else {
            hi = mid - 1;  // Should be mid, not mid-1, why?
        }
    }
    return lo;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4};  // Bitonic array
    System.out.println(getMaxIndex(a));  // Should be 5 
}
```

Comment: For Binary Search to work, the array should be sorted first of all and if it's sorted, the max will either be the first or the last element. Why need to do all that computation?

Can you explain your problem statement?

Comment: Sorry I didn't tell the context that I'm looking for a key in a bitonic array (where elements ascend first then descend). If I sort the elements at first I will disorganize the order. @VirGandhi

Comment: Could you post a few example question and expected output?

Comment: Sure, I just edited my post. @ArunGowda

Comment: The max of your array if 9, not 5. I believe you want 5 when you say so, only you need to describe what you want in a different way than saying *max*.

Comment: I lost the word "index" in the call. The index of 9 is 5, so getMaxIndex should return 5. @OleV.V.

Comment: [Find the maximum element in an array which is first increasing and then decreasing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-element-in-an-array-which-is-first-increasing-and-then-decreasing/). Scroll down to *Method 2 (Binary Search)*.

Comment: @SaeronMeng, does your code run infinitely for a valid bitonic array or only for invalid input say `[1, 2]`?

Comment: If I use mid-1, neither of the cases can get the result, as kutschkem said under your solution. @Horse

Comment: @SaeronMeng, Your code should work fine for valid bitonic array. It can fail only for invalid bitonic array.

Comment: Yes, as long as I assign the correct index for hi in Line 9. @Horse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you had was that you were not always changing `mid`. In your example, at one point `lo` is 4 and pointing to `7` in the array while `hi` is 5 and points to `9`. In the situation where `lo` and `hi` are just 1 apart, `mid` is set to `lo`. Here you are comparing `a[mid] > a[mid-1]`. Problem 1, `mid-1` is out of range and in rare cases gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Second, if the condition is `true`, you set `lo` to `mid`, which is the value it already had. You are getting nowhere. You are in an infinite loop.

I tried your method with

```
    System.out.println(getMaxIndex(new int[] { 3 , 8 })); // Expecting 1
```

I got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 2`

The solution is in the answer by Horse.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the exact error. I think, the OP's code works fine for a bitonic array (increasing and decreasing) and will fail only for a non-bitonic array (say ascending sorted array, it will get stuck on the last 2 elements)

Comment: @Horse Thanks for your comment. (1) OP^s code went into an infinite loop on the bitonic array in the question. (2) I believe that by usual definition a purely ascending array is considered bitonic, only having its max at its end. After all [8] is a decreasing sequence of one element. Similarly for a descending array, only the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

### bitonic array

The numbers are strictly increasing and after an index, the numbers are strictly decreasing

eg: `[15, 20, 26, 5, 1]`

If the array contains only unique elements, then maximum can be found using following conditions

1. iterate while `left index < right index`
2. compute `middle index` (towards left incase no single middle index)
3. if the value at middle is smaller than next element, then move towards right
4. else move left towards left

`arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1]` will never throw out of bounds exception as `left < right` invariant is maintained on the loop. hence `mid`(index) will always be lesser than `right`(index) and hence there is atleast one index after `mid`

```java
int left = 0, right = arr.length - 1;
while (left < right) {
  int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
  if (arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1]) {
    left = mid + 1;
  } else {
    right = mid;
  }
}
return arr[left]; // or arr[right]
```

```
              15        20        26         5         1
l=0, r=4      l                   m                    r
m=2

a[m] > a[m+1] l                   r                  
so, r=m

l=0, r=2      l         m         r
m=1

a[m] < a[r+1]                      l,r
m=l+1

Now exit while loop l == r and return value at l or r
```

### Analysis of OP's code

1. A simple reproducible example is [1, 2] - this will cause `lo` to be stuck to same index and causes infinite loop.
2. Any dataset that reduces to `lo + 1 == hi` and `arr[lo] < arr[hi]` will set `mid` to `lo` (`lo + (hi - lo) / 2` will be `lo`) and hence the assignment `lo = mid` causes an infinite loop

Comment: It's not sorted and rotated. It's ascending then descending

Comment: @ArunGowda, Oh ok. i will update the answer

Comment: Arun, it's sorted and rotated from some point.

Comment: A little bit explanation would be good here. The issue with OPs code that your code fixes is that if lo - high = 1, then mid = lo, so there is an infinite loop. Also with a two-element array the code just breaks. Your version avoids these issues.

Comment: I'm clear after reading Horse's code and kutschkem's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the word `bitonic` means, array is sorted in increasing order, and after some point (may be) it starting to decrease.

Likewise, you have to find the pivot point where array is starting to decrease (if it is exist), if you can able to find the point, `that's it`, this pivotal point is your answer.

so i am attaching some input/output sequence to make it more clear:

```
{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4}; --> should  return 5 (index at which element is maximum)
{15, 20, 26, 5, 1} --> should return 2 (index at which element is maximum)
{0, 1, 2, 3} --> should return 3 (index at which element is maximum)
```

now you have to modify your code like following:

```
public static int getMaxIndex(int[] arr) {
    int  left = 0, right = arr.length - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
      int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
      if(mid == 0 || mid == arr.length-1) {
            // if no such pivotal point exist in sequence/array
            return mid;
        }else if(arr[mid] > arr[mid+1] && arr[mid] > arr[mid-1]){               
            // it's the pivotal point, where element at left side smaller and element at right side too
            return mid;
        }
      if (arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1]) {
        left = mid + 1;
      } else {
        right = mid;
      }
    }
    return -1;
}
```